# Importing additional custom data in DIMACS format

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import

I have graphs in [DIMACS format](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/DIMACS.html), with vertex colors specified. The vertex colors are denoted by lines `n u c`, where `u` is the vertex number and `c` an integer representing its color.

Here's an example of a triangle colored with 2 colors:

```
p edge 3 3
e 1 2
e 2 3
e 3 1
n 1 1
n 2 1
n 3 2
```

Using [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/DIMACS.html), I can nicely import the graph, but not the vertex colors. Is there a way to read them in with `Import`, or am I forced to write my own reader that manually sets the vertex colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't be to be a way to `Import` the colours. The only available information are the following:

```
{#, Import["~/test.col", #]} & /@ Import["~/test.col", "Elements"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Thus you indeed need to `Import` your `Graph` from the `.col` file and add the colours afterwards:

```
g = Import@"~/test.col";
data = Import["~/test.col", "List"];
vclist = ToExpression /@ ((StringReplace[#, " " -> ","] & /@ 
           StringTrim /@ (StringCases[data, "n" ~~ x__ :> x] /. {} :> Sequence[])) /. 
             List[x_String] :> "{" ~~ x ~~ "}");
col = Module[{}, SeedRandom@(#^2); RGBColor@RandomReal[{}, {3}]] &;
vc = (Rule @@@ ({#, col@#2} & @@@ vclist))
```

> ```
> {1 -> RGBColor[{0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526}], 
>  2 -> RGBColor[{0.817389, 0.11142, 0.789526}], 
>  3 -> RGBColor[{0.311376, 0.566004, 0.627155}]}
> ```

Now one can recreate the `Graph` `g` with coloured vertices:

```
Graph[EdgeList@g, VertexCoordinates -> AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates], 
  VertexStyle -> vc, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]